# How to detect when `prepublish` script is executed as a result of running `npm install`

Tags: node.js, npm

https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts

> prepublish: Run BEFORE the package is published. (Also run on local npm install without any arguments.)

I want my script to execute only in case of user executing `npm publish`. However, NPM will execute "prepublish" script if user runs "npm install".

Answer (score 5):

The only way I have figured out is using NPM internal ENV variables:

```
// NPM will run prepublish script after `npm install` (https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts)
// This ensures that when script is executed using `npm *` it is run only when the command is `npm publish`.
if (process.env.npm_config_argv) {
    let npmConfigArgv;

    npmConfigArgv = JSON.parse(process.env.npm_config_argv);

    if (npmConfigArgv.original[0] !== 'publish') {
        console.log('`bundle-dependencies prepublish` will not execute. It appears that `prepublish` script has been run by `npm install`.');

        return;
    }
}
```

It appears that NPM stores the original command in `process.env.npm_config_argv` variable.

In case you are wondering, each NPM script is being run in different process. Therefore, something like setting a custom ENV variable in `preinstall` script does not work.

Comment: Looking at https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/3059 this seems to have been a very controversial decision. One workaround I've been using is doing `npm install --ignore-scripts` (as suggested in the script above).

Comment: where do you place this code? is your prepublish script written in `js` and run by `node`? How do you call this from your `package.json` file ?

Answer (score 2):

Another solution that's also worked for me (again from [this thread](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/3059)) is using a `prepublish.sh` script like the following:

```
get_json_val() {
    python -c "import json,sys;sys.stdout.write(json.dumps(json.load(sys.stdin)$1))";
}
get_npm_command() {
    local temp=$(echo $npm_config_argv | get_json_val "['original'][0]")
    echo "$temp" | tr -dc "[:alnum:]"
}
if [ $(get_npm_command) != "publish" ]; then
    echo "Skipping prepublish script"
    exit 0
fi
# else
echo "prepublish called"
# prepublish logic follows:
# ...
```

So if your `package.json` file is:

```
{
  "name": "foo",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "main": "lib/foo.js",
  "scripts": {
       "prepublish": "./prepublish.sh"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.10.0"
  }
}
```

… then running `npm install` will *only* install the dependencies and the `prepublish` target will *only* be called when user types `npm run publish`.

Yet another way is to use the `in-publish` package (again mentioned in [this thread](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/3059)). Place it in your development dependencies and then in your `package.json` have something like:

```
"prepublish": "(in-publish && npm run clean && flow check && npm run test && npm run build) || not-in-publish"
```

Answer (score 1):

As of **npm@4.0.0**, the [`prepublish` script is now *deprecated*](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#prepublish-and-prepare). To run a script on both `npm publish`, and `npm install` without arguments (the bahaviour of `prepublish`), you should use **`prepare`** instead.

To run a script only on `npm publish`, you should use **`prepublishOnly`**.